# Match text excluding some part of matched text from result

Tags: .net, regex, delphi, delphi-xe2

is this possible to exclude some text from result in regex?
this is only a sample but show the problem:

```
23d14aaa17d19
```

and i need result whith 2 matches without "d"

```
2314
1719
```

i try this

```
\d+(?:[a-z])\d+
```

but it exclude only from Groups collection not from matched result text
result is

```
23d14
17d19
```

is this possible with regex?

PS. i read "manual" on stackoverflow but without success

Comment: AFAIK you can't exclude a specific character from a match group, just do the match and remove `d` afterwards.

Comment: Is this really true? How this is possible that no-one implement this in regex? I try to believe but i can not :/

Comment: Hi - maybe - using a temporary variable - loop through each char of the string, removing the chars you don't need, use the temp string then to do the matching : for I := 0 to length(str) do begin if not  str[I] in ['a','b', 'c'] then tempstr := tempstr + str[I]; .... excuse the syntax but hope it helps

Comment: Is your question about Delphi, or about .NET? Delphi does not produce .NET (managed) applications, and .NET doesn't execute Delphi applications, and your question mentions no specific programming language and provides no code in either language. What programming question are you asking? If it's about the regex only, please remove the tags that don't apply. If it's about Delphi, please remove the .NET tag. Thanks.

Comment: I add tags Delphi and .Net because i use regex in delphi xe2 and also in VS C# .net and MVC .Net and i do not need answer from java and something other regex formats

Answer (score 0):

Livius, how about this regex:

```
^(\d+)[a-z]+(\d+)[a-z]+(\d+)[a-z]+(\d+)
```

Using it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
class Program {
static void Main()    {
string s1 = @"23d14aaa17d19";
var myRegex = new Regex(@"^(\d+)[a-z]+(\d+)[a-z]+(\d+)[a-z]+(\d+)");
Match OneMatch = myRegex.Match(s1);
if (OneMatch.Success)    {
    Console.WriteLine(OneMatch.Groups[1].Value + OneMatch.Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(OneMatch.Groups[3].Value + OneMatch.Groups[4].Value);
    }
Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
} // END Main
} // END Program
```

**Output:**

```
2314
1719
```

Comment: I know how to do this in loop or using group and eliminate group in bigger code. But this should be simple possible in simple match. I see that this is not possible :/ I vote on first comment.